# How can I set an image poster correctly in video tag

Tags: html, css

I set the video at the desktop page version. I would like to change that video to the image when the page width is less than 480px (for the mobile version). I've already set a poster for the video tag but don't know how to make the image to be shown correctly on mobiles (now it is the only video shown on all devices). Please, tell me how to set an image correctly.
Thanks

```css
.video {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <main class="main">
        <div class="main-background">
            <video preload="none" autoplay playsinline muted loop class="video"              
                poster="./images/beach.jpg" id="video">
                <source src="./video/Atropicallandscape.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaScript solution

You could use JavaScript to determine the media size using `matchMedia()` => ***MDN:** method returns a new **MediaQueryList** object that can then be used to determine if the document matches the media query string, as well as to monitor the document to detect when it matches (or stops matching) that media query.*

In your HTML, add the image element in your video elements parent element and add a helper class to toggle `display: none;` on the elements style in your CSS to be used when your media query matches the size you want.

Then you create a function and pass the **event** in to the function that checks the size of the browser using ***event.matches*** => `e.matches`. A conditional can be used to handle the switching of display for the elements. You can use a helper class that simply defines the display property as none which can be toggled back and forth if truthy using `el.classList.add`/`el.classList.remove`.

Then add an eventListener to use your function that checks the size of your devices screen size.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main-background')
const video = main.querySelector('.video')
const image = main.querySelector('.image')

const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 450px)')

function handleChange(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    video.classList.add('hidden')
    image.classList.remove('hidden')
  }else{
    image.classList.add('hidden')
    video.classList.remove('hidden')
  }
}

mediaQuery.addListener(handleChange)
```

```css
.video {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.image {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/450/450') no-repeat;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="main-background">
    <video preload="none" autoplay playsinline muted loop class="video" poster="./images/beach.jpg" id="video">
      <source src="./video/Atropicallandscape.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="image hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```